# Failed to build sqlite3 native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to install older version of sqllite3:

I tried:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'
```

But I get:

```
EMP-SOF-LT075:admin_pci test$ sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180820-14374-qv6ltl.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-sqlite3lib
    --without-sqlite3lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
EMP-SOF-LT075:admin_pci plamen$
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried suggested _“`sqlite3` is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3'”_?

Comment: I get Warning: sqlite 3.24.0 is already installed and up-to-date. I need to install older version 1.3.13

Comment: Check the documentation on `brew` for how to install the specific version of the package? I do not use non-robust operating systems, like MacOS, sorry.

Comment: Try `brew unlink sqlite3 && brew link sqlite3`

Answer (score 6):

Please try to run the following commands:

For MAC Users,

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/lib
```

And if you are using ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Hope this will solve your problem.